# C++ / Linux - Is it possible to inject context specific data into every thread created

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I have a concept of an application context that is created and used for some scope within my process.  This context can hold things like context-specific singletons.  Whenever I create a thread, I pass the context along to the thread so all code within the thread can view the same context.
This all works fine and dandy, but the issue I'm hitting comes along when threads are created by 3rd party libraries that are outside of my control.

I'm trying to find a way to intercept all thread creation in my application so that I can ensure contexts are passed along to all threads, whether I created them or not.  I'm trying to avoid intercepting pthread_create mainly because I dont want to have to rely on LD_PRELOAD for this.
If there was some way to get a thread's "parent" thread id I can lookup the parent's context, but it doesnt look like thats possible.
If there was some thread-specific property that I can set which would get inherited by all child threads, that might work, but again I dont see anything viable.

**TLDR**; is there any possible way to get my parent thread's context passed through to a child thread that I dont create directly, without LD_PRELOAD-ing a pthread_create intercept method?

EDIT: Im not sure what code to post here, but this is what it looks like when I do control thread creation.  I use my own thread class instead of std::thread that wraps the method to call and passes the context through:

```
class thread : public std::thread
{
public:
    thread() {}

    template< class Function, class... Args > 
    explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args ) : thread( "", std::forward<Function>( f ), std::forward<Args>( args )... )
    {}

    template< class Function, class... Args > 
    explicit thread( const char * thread_name, Function&& f, Args&&... args ) : std::thread( thread::wrap<std::decay_t<Function>,std::decay_t<Args>...>,
                                                                                             AppContext::impl(), std::forward<Function>( f ), std::forward<Args>( args )... )
    {
        if( thread_name && *thread_name )
            setThreadName( thread_name );
    }

    void setThreadName( const char * thread_name );

private:
    template< class Function, class... Args > 
    static void wrap( std::weak_ptr<AppContextImpl> impl, Function&& f, Args&&... args )
    {
       AppContext threadContext( impl );
       f( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    }
};
```

Comment: What about just `thread_local`? Please show some example code you have in mind. How does the 3rd party library look like? You sound like the 3rd party doesn't allow you to specify context to the callback function, but a small code would probably be much clearer. Also, can you specify the callback function itself for the 3rd party? Why do you want to pass "context" to those "threads" and what do you mean by that?

Comment: If you have multiple contexts, how would you know which one should go with the thread created by the 3rd party library?

Comment: essentially my context *is* a thread_local variable that I want to pass through to all child threads.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm if i were to intercept pthread_create, i know the proper context at the time of the call.  Alternatively, if I know the threads "parent" thread i can look up the parent thread's local context.

Comment: `: public std::thread` - why? Inheriting from standard library is, well, discouraged at lest.

Comment: How/why are threads being started by third party libraries? Do you pass them a callback which they invoke? If so, I have some ideas you could use

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez yes they eventually invoke callbacks, and the callbacks may need to lookup context-specific data

Comment: Are the callbacks C functions, or C++ lambdas? Also, can the context be determined at compile-time (so that it can be looked up with an enum or an int), or is it created at run-time?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez created at runtime, multiple threads can at any time have different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Why would a thread internal to the library require your context variables? That thread might not run a single line of your code, which means it doesn't need your data either.

Therefore, the easiest solution is to wrap access to that context in a class. The class will instantiate a copy of the context on first access. No access, no context creation, no overhead.

Comment: The library invokes callbacks into my code which may need context-specific data

Answer (score 0):

A variable with thread local storage achieves your need of having separate context for each thread.

Initialising this context from the so called "parent" thread context is the tricky part. Only way to achieve this as far as I can tell is to pass the parent context to the callback that is executed on the thread. Any reasonable library that creates threads with callbacks provides a way to pass at least a pointer to custom data.

Example:

```
struct context {
    const char* name;
};

context& get_context(context* parent_context)
{
    thread_local context
        my_context = parent_context
                   ? *parent_context
                   : context{
                       "initial context"
                   };
   return my_context;
}

void callback(context* parent_context)
{
    assert(parent_context);
    context& my_context = get_context(parent_context);
    std::cout << "callback, before mod:\t\t"
              << my_context.name
              << '\n';

    my_context.name = "context was changed";

    std::cout << "callback, after mod:\t\t"
              <<my_context.name
              << '\n';
}

int main() {
    context& my_context = get_context(nullptr);
    std::cout << "main, before thread:\t\t"
              << my_context.name
              << '\n';

    auto t = std::thread(callback, my_context);
    t.join();

    std::cout << "main, after thread:\t\t"
              << my_context.name
              << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This would require me to be able to know about and account for every thread / callback situation which is not feasible.  I'm looking for a solution that would capture all threads created in my application without any additional work